# How to access the "props/data" outside the instance? vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently using component:

```
Vue.component('form', require('./components/Form.vue').default);
```

Inside the **Form.vue**, I am trying to get the `props` value of `name` (See code below)

```
let TEMPLATES = {
    alpha: this.name + " is required."

    //more codes here
}

export default{
    props: {
        name: ''
    }

    //more codes here
}
```

But I ended up to this error below. Somebody knows how to do this?

> TypeError: undefined has no properties

Comment: What is the exact purpose to access the variable **outside** of the instance? Maybe there could be an easier solution which profits from the vuejs lifecycle or something else

Comment: Props are sent into a component, so could you add the line of code where you are calling the component and sending in the props? It might look something like this:    
`<form :name="SomeNameHere"></form>`